# can we use a mongodb 3.0 and mongodb 2.6 in same replica set?

Tags: mongodb, replication

i know that replicas using different storage engines can coexist in a replica set on MongoDB 3.0  but can we add a MongoDB 3.0 replica to a replica set that consists of MongoDB 2.6 instances ?

That would be the easiest way to port to "MongoDB 3.0 + wiredTiger" instances from our MongoDB 2.6 instances

Comment: As long as the 3.0 is a secondary i don't think you will have an issue. Backwards compatibility is supported in replication.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a [rolling upgrade of your replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#upgrade-a-replica-set-to-3-0) from MongoDB 2.6 to 3.0.

While a mixed version 2.6/3.0 replica set is supported for the purposes of upgrading, you should not run with this configuration for longer than is required.

You should also read the [3.0 upgrade](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/) and [compatibility change](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/) notes carefully, as important considerations will be included there. As with any upgrade, you should test in a development/staging environment before prior to your production release.

A few particular points to be aware of:

- Before enabling the new WiredTiger storage engine, ensure that all replica set/sharded cluster members are running at least MongoDB version 2.6.8, and preferably version 3.0.0 or newer.
- Once upgraded to MongoDB 3.0, you cannot downgrade to a version lower than 2.6.5
- If you upgrade to 3.0 and have run `authSchemaUpgrade`, you cannot downgrade to 2.6 without disabling `--auth` or restoring a pre-upgrade backup. The `authSchemaUpgrade` discards MONGODB-CR authentication credentials used in MongoDB 2.6.